# Best way to read specific length of bytes from a stream?

Tags: c#, stream

What is the best way to read a specific length of bytes from a stream?

Comment: By calling the Read/ReadAsync method ? Define best!

Answer (score -1):

The default .Read method already forces you to specify a length/count.

```
public abstract int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
```

with you can use like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

A NetworkStream (for example) may not read the total count so you need to write a loop like the microsoft sample already describes:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.IO.Stream.Read%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework